# Setting the width for the react-mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mapbox

im trying to make the map responsive to my site so i added if statements but it doesnt work, the width only changes when i manually edit one. can someone plz help been trying to solve this but i just dont understand why its not working

```
let phone = "320";
let tablet = "900";
let bigScreen = "2600";
let bigLaptop = "1400";
let laptop = "1000";
function useWindowSize() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(calculateWidth());
  useEffect(() => {
    function updateSize() {
      console.log("hey");
      setWidth(calculateWidth());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);

    return () => {
      console.log();
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateSize);
    };
  }, []);

  function calculateWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth < bigScreen && window.innerWidth > bigLaptop) {
      return "70vw";
    } else if (window.innerWidth < bigLaptop && window.innerWidth > laptop) {
      return "67vw";
    } else if (window.innerWidth < laptop && window.innerWidth > phone) {
      return "60vw";
    } else {
      return "100vw";
    }
  }
  return width;
}

//For map API location Bali
export function Map() {
  const mediaWidth = useWindowSize();
  console.log();
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: -8.340539,
    longitude: 115.091949,
    width: mediaWidth,
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 10,
  });
```

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS?

Comment: [I created an example that might help you out](https://codepen.io/alexmckay/pen/WNwKJZz?editors=1100) might help you out

Comment: if i could id already do it lol, i change change the size of the map container but the map itself seeps out of the container so the only way to set the width is by using the jsx

Comment: I have updated the example. You need to set the child element (in this case a canvas element) to be a percentage value of a parent container (in this case a div). The div element can then be adjusted using media queries and css. I work with maps almost everyday at work and I have never found a reason to change width with Javascript instead of CSS.

Comment: thanks for that man, but idk why the map still seeps out not the map image but i can still click on the map outside of the container. anyway solved it but ill use this if i use a map again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should track changing value of `mediawidth` with useEffect like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setViewport(state => ({
    ...state,
    width: mediaWidth
  }));
}, [mediaWidth]);
```

But maybe you can use Flexbox, CSS Grid Layout, or Media Queries to achieve what you want to do easily.

Comment: yo thanks so much man this is awesome, could u explain to me why i had to add this plz? cuz it works but i dont know why

Comment: You set `viewport` state that includes `mediaWidth` in your Map Component, but it's just the initial setting of `viewport` state. 

Since `mediaWidth` will change every time the user resize the window, and you defined `viewport.width` as state, you should update `viewport` state too with the updated `mediaWidth`'s value through `setViewport`.